# How to add proper validation for password and confirm password input using HTML 5 patterns?

Tags: php, html, pattern-matching

I am using this script ,it makes neccessary for a user to use a capital letter and a lower case alphabe.t

```html
<input title="Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers" type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}" maxlength="20" name="password" onchange="
  this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? this.title : '');
  if(this.checkValidity()) form.confirm_password.pattern = this.value;
" placeholder="Password"/>
                            <input title="Please enter the same Password as above" type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}" name="confirm_password" onchange="
  this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? this.title : '');"  placeholder="Confirm Password" maxlength="20" id="confirm_password">
```

***I don't want to use an extra java script for this sole pourpose.***
And I wanted that user can either input a speacial character or a Capital letter.

So Anyone can help me provide with a good regex that satisfies my requirement.
Which are

- Capital Letters (A-Z) (Not neccassary but allowed)
- Lowercase Letters (a-z) (Neccassary)
- Numbers (0-9)  (Neccassary)
- Speacial  Letters(!@#$%^&*>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with more validations if you want.

```
    function CheckPassword(inputtext) {
        var error = "";
        var LtrNoUS = /^\w+$/;
        var No = /[0-9]/;
        var UC = /[A-Z]/;
        var match = /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/;
        if (inputtext == "") {
            alert('Password can not be empty');
            return false;
        }
        if (!match.test(inputtext)) {
            alert('Password must have only letter,number & underscore');
            return false;
        }
        if (!No.test(inputtext)) {
            alert('Password must have at least 1 number');
            return false;
        }
        if (!UC.test(inputtext)) {
            alert('Password Must have at least 1 uppercase letter');
            return false;
        }
        if (inputtext.length < 4) {
            alert('Too Short Password');
            return false;
        }
        if (inputtext.length > 16) {
            alert('Too Long Password');
            return false;
        }
        if (inputtext.length < 5) {
            alert('Weak Password');
        } else if ((inputtext.length > 5) && (password.length < 9)) {
            alert('Medium Password');
        } else if ((inputtext.length >= 9) && (inputtext.length < 16)) {
            alert('Strong Password');
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I want to do all this using pattern matching for which I need a REGEX as specified in my question.

Answer (score -2):

You can go with this:

```
<form name="form1" action="#">  
<ul>  
<li><input type="password" name="pwd1"/></li>  
<li>&nbsp;</li>  
<li class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="CheckPassword(document.form1.pwd1)"/></li>  
<li>&nbsp;</li>  
</ul>  
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function CheckPassword(inputtxt)   
{   
   var passw=  /^[A-Za-z]\w{7,14}$/;  
   if(inputtxt.value.match(passw))   
   {   
      alert('Correct, try another...')  
      return true;  
   }  
   else  
   {   
      alert('Wrong...!')  
      return false;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: All HTML element attribute values should be wrapped in double quotes, not single quote.